# How can I convert a bunch of files from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 using Perl?

Tags: php, perl, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have several documents I need to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 (without the BOM of course). This is the issue though. I have so many of these documents (it is actually a mix of documents, some UTF-8 and some ISO-8859-1) that I need an automated way of converting them. Unfortunately I only have ActivePerl installed and don't know much about encoding in that language. I may be able to install PHP, but I am not sure as this is not my personal computer.

Just so you know, I use Scite or Notepad++, but both do not convert correctly. For example, if I open a document in Czech that contains the character "ž" and go to the "Convert to UTF-8" option in Notepad++, it incorrectly converts it to an unreadable character.

There is a way I CAN convert them, but it is tedious. If I open the document with the special characters and copy the document to Windows clipboard, then paste it into a UTF-8 document and save it, it is okay. This is too tedious (opening every file and copying/pasting into a new document) for the amount of documents I have.

Any ideas?
Thanks!!!

Comment: "ž" isn't an ISO-8859-1 character, but it is in Windows-1252. You may be running in a locale specific 8-bit encoding. More details needed.

Comment: I actually think the document is encoded in ANSI. I mistakenly wrote what the charset was set to in the meta tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the character 'ž' is included then the encoding is definitely not ISO-8859-1 ("Latin 1") but is probably CP1252 ("Win Latin 1").  Dealing with a mix of UTF8, ISO-8859-1 and CP1252 (possibly even in the same file) is exactly what the [Encoding::FixLatin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encoding-FixLatin/) Perl module is designed for.

You can install the module from CPAN by running this command:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install 'Encoding::FixLatin'"
```

You could then write a short Perl script that uses the Encoding::FixLatin module, but there's an even easier way.  The module comes with a command called `fix_latin` which takes mixed encoding on standard input and writes UTF8 on standard output.  So you could use a command line like this to convert one file:

```
fix_latin <input-file.txt >output-file.txt
```

If you're running Windows then the fix_latin command might not be in your path and might not have been run through pl2bat in which case you'd need to do something like:

```
perl C:\perl\bin\fix_latin.pl <input-file.txt >output-file.txt
```

The exact paths and filenames would need to be adjusted for your system.

To run `fix_latin` across a whole bunch of files would be trivial on a Linux system but on Windows you'd probably need to use the powershell or similar.

Comment: thanks a lot grant! your script worked very well with the fix_latin command. ill figure out a way to run it through multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a valid answer to your particular question, but have you looked at the [GNU iconv tool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html)? It's fairly generally available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to cygwin or are able to download a couple of common *nix tools (you'll need bash, grep, iconv and file, all of which are available for windows via, say, [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html)), you might be able to write a rather simple shell script that does the job.

The script would **approximately** look as follows:

```
for f in *;
do
   if file $f | grep 'ISO-8859' > /dev/null;
   then
      cat $f | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 > $f.converted;
   else
      echo "Not converting $f"
   fi;
done;
```

You'll need to test the steps though, e.g. I'm not sure what would "file" exactly say for a ISO-8859 document.